# php 7.0 fpm separate error logs for pools not working

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, fpm

I get 500 status on some of the php pages for Sentrifugo and to find out what
's going wrong I tried setting up error logging

The configuration can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anadimisra/8db36c679127712c19d2b71e7ff096c5)

However, on the pages that I get a 500, I do not see any log entries in any of these files

```
/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log
/var/log/php_errors.log
```

The worker pool log diectory is empty

```
anadi@foo:~$ sudo ls -ltr /var/log/php-fpm/
total 0
```

All I see is a 500 status logged in the access.log with no imformation at all that could help me troubleshoot

```
XX.XXX.XX.XX - - [13/Mar/2017:13:48:53 +0530] "GET /index.php/wizard/configuresite HTTP/2.0" 500 390 "https://foo.bar.com/index.php/wizard/managemenu" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

There's no entries in /var/log/nginx/foo/error.log neither

**Update**

All log directories are writable by the respective owner

```
anadi@foo:~$ ps -ef | grep php
root     19453     1  0 15:24 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 19458 19453  0 15:24 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 19459 19453  0 15:24 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www

anadi@foo:~$ ls -ltr /var/log/ | grep php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       1679 Mar 13 10:47 php_errors.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data   4096 Mar 13 15:23 php-fpm
-rw------- 1 root     root      13590 Mar 13 15:24 php7.0-fpm.log

anadi@foo:~$ ls -ltr /var/log/php-fpm/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    0 Mar 13 15:23 www.error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2041 Mar 13 15:34 www.access.log

anadi@foo:~$ ps -ef | grep nginx
root     19632     1  0 15:27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 19633 19632  0 15:27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 19634 19632  0 15:27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process

anadi@foo:~$ ls -ltr /var/www/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  3 21:18 html
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 13 15:31 foo

anadi@foo:~$ ls -ltr /var/log/nginx/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 13 09:58 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     1105 Mar 13 15:08 error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     5384 Mar 13 15:41 access.log
```

Did changes to `display_errors` setting as explained in one of the answers, but this still does not give any helpful log output for troubleshooting.

Here's extract of `var/log/php-fpm/www.acccess.log`

```
- -  13/Mar/2017:15:32:11 +0530 "GET /index.php" 500 /var/www/tribe/index.php 34.722 2048 57.60%
- -  13/Mar/2017:15:34:14 +0530 "GET /index.php" 500 /var/www/tribe/index.php 20.952 4096 95.46%
```

Comment: you need to check your nginx error log , instead of access log , in ubuntu it's often be under this path : `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: @hassan I've seen them too, no error messages related to this request

Comment: 500 error means the often there are a syntax error in your script which had executed in the server, put the code of this action `configuresite` to check out

Comment: I do understand that, but how come the error is not being written in logs given the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

search for log file in your project

And In your php.ini you can find display_errors = Off make it equal On

Comment: be sure that log file is writable

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but downgrading to PHP 5 solved all of it, error logs populate as expected, and the intermittent 500 status codes have disappeared